# A sword/dagger fighter escapes his home planet, meets a girl, and has many adventures

Tags: story-identification

I read this book around the year 2000. It is about a young dagger/sword
dancer (or fighter) who escapes his home planet and goes into a
self-conscious space shuttle. Another girl (from the same planet, if I
remember) also escapes the planet, and they meet each other at that
space shuttle. This machine on which they are about to embark their journey
has a name like Theo, or Theophile or something like that (definitely
Theo.. in it.)

It's a trilogy, or consisting of at least 3 books. At the end of it, the couple
tell Theo that the girl is pregnant "Theo.. you are becoming uncle!",
however Theo informs them that this shuttle can't sustain more than 2
people, and they settle down on some planet

Dear all! This is all I can remember! I thoroughly enjoyed reading this
book and would do anything if anyone can tell me what the author/title was!

Comment: Did she actually say "you are becoming uncle!" as per broken English, or is there a missing article there?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I read this book in Dutch.